# My UIActivityIndicator cannot move

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I add a large white activity indicator on my master view, but it is fixed, i cannot move it to a appropriate place.  (shown in the following link)

[screenshot](http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/a74ecc4cjw1dzxtqt39yej.jpg)

Comment: show some code so we can understand something.

Comment: thanks @CRDave , someone has already gave the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add an activitiy indicator to the cell here. You have to have a normal view as superview for it, the table view content area cannot be it, since this is being filled at runtime with cells.

Comment: You can also add it as a table footer view (the activity indicator in the screenshot is clearly not part of the prototype cell). Adding a plain `UIView` as a footer and then adding the activity indicator as a subview of that would allow to freely position it within the footer.

Comment: If you want to position the activity indicator in the center then you have to have something else but a table view to mount on. Developers usually use a normal view controller and then add a table view as subclass of this VC's view. This way you have a view to mount stuff on that does not move with the table.

Answer (score 0):

Make "Recent Photos **Table View Controller**" as "Recent Photos **View Controller**"

ie) Make it Subclass of UIViewController, NOT UITableViewController.